# how can i play a mp3 file added locally in project, when app is in background?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I am working on a service provider app, which plays a mp3 file when provider receives a request. it works fine when app is in active mode but its not working when app is in background mode.

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/5817-background-modes-tutorial-getting-started

Answer (score 0):

Allow audio play in the background.[image]

Answer (score 0):

write following code and set/tick mark Audio and Airplay property from capabilities

```
do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: [.mixWithOthers, .allowAirPlay])
    print("Playback OK")
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    print("Session is Active")
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

[image]